# How does a Recursive CTE run, line by line?

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I think I've got the format of Recursive CTEs down well enough to write one, but still find myself frustrated to no end that I cannot manually process one (pretend to be the SQL engine myself and reach the result set with pen and paper). [I've found this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/InsideRecursiveCtes.aspx), which is close to what I'm looking for, but not detailed enough. I have no problem tracing through a C++ recursive function and understanding how it runs -- but for SQL I don't understand why or how the engine knows to stop. Does the anchor and recursive block get called everytime, or is the anchor skipped in later iterations? (I doubt it but I'm trying to expression my confusion about the way it seems to jump around.) If the anchor is called each time, how does the anchor not appear multiple times in the final result? I hope someone can just do a break down line 1 line 2, etc. what happens and what is "in memory" as the result set accumulates.

I've taken the liberty of stealing my [example from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757370/recursive-same-table-query-in-sql-server-2008/1758797%231758797), since it seems to be the easiest to understand.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( 
      Id INT 
    , [Name] VARCHAR(20) 
    , ParentId INT 
) 

INSERT INTO @tbl( Id, Name, ParentId ) 
VALUES 
     (1, 'Europe', NULL) 
    ,(2, 'Asia',   NULL) 
    ,(3, 'Germany',   1) 
    ,(4, 'UK',        1) 
    ,(5, 'China',     2) 
    ,(6, 'India',     2) 
    ,(7, 'Scotland',  4) 
    ,(8, 'Edinburgh', 7) 
    ,(9, 'Leith',     8)  
; 

WITH abcd 
    AS ( 
        -- anchor 
        SELECT  id, Name, ParentID, 
                CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS Path 
        FROM    @tbl 
        WHERE   ParentId IS NULL 
        UNION ALL 
          --recursive member 
        SELECT  t.id, t.Name, t.ParentID, 
                CAST((a.path + '/' + t.Name) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path"
        FROM    @tbl AS t 
                JOIN abcd AS a 
                  ON t.ParentId = a.id 
       )
SELECT * FROM abcd
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Think of a recursive `CTE` as of an endless `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH    rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   anchor_condition
        ),
        rows2 AS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    set_operation(mytable, rows)
        ),
        rows3 AS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    set_operation(mytable, rows2)
        ),
        …
SELECT  *
FROM    rows
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    rows2
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    rows3
UNION ALL
…
```

In your case, that would be:

```
WITH    abcd1 AS
        ( 
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @tbl t
        WHERE   ParentId IS NULL 
        ),
        abcd2 AS
        ( 
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    abcd1
        JOIN    @tbl t
        ON      t.ParentID = abcd1.id
        ),
        abcd3 AS
        ( 
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    abcd2
        JOIN    @tbl t
        ON      t.ParentID = abcd2.id
        ),
        abcd4 AS
        ( 
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    abcd3
        JOIN    @tbl t
        ON      t.ParentID = abcd3.id
        ),
        abcd5 AS
        ( 
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    abcd4
        JOIN    @tbl t
        ON      t.ParentID = abcd4.id
        ),
        abcd6 AS
        ( 
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    abcd5
        JOIN    @tbl t
        ON      t.ParentID = abcd5.id
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd1
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd2
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd3
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd4
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd5
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd6
```

Since `abcd6` yields no results, this implies a stopping condition.

Theoretically, a recursive `CTE` can be infinite, but practically, `SQL Server` tries to forbid the queries that would lead to infinite recordsets.

You may want to read this article:

- [**SQL Server: are the recursive CTE’s really set-based?**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/18/sql-server-are-the-recursive-ctes-really-set-based/)

Comment: Lovely Explanation Quassnoi !

Comment: plus 1 i understood that reference

Answer (score 42):

The algorithm that CTE use is:

1. Execute the anchor part, get result **r0**
2. Execute the recursive part, using **r0** as input, and get result **r1** (not null)
3. Execute the recursive part, using **r1** as input, and get result **r2** (not null)
4. Execute the recursive part, using **r3** as input, and get result **r3** (not null)
   ...
5. Execute the recursive part, using **r(n-1)** as input, and output **rn** (null). This time **rn** is null, so we use **UNION ALL** to combine **r0, r1, r2 ... r(n-1)** and that's the final result

Lets take an example:

```
WITH    cte ( value )
          AS (
               SELECT   1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   value + 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    value < 4
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
```

The result of this query is:

```
value
-----------
1
2
3
4

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Let's examine it step by step:

```
Execute anchor query (SELECT 1), we got:
  r0 = 1
  cte = r0 = 1

    |
    |
    V

Now we execute
SELECT value + 1 FROM cte WHERE value < 4
Since cte is r0 (only has 1), we got:
  r1 = 2
  cte = r1 = 2

    |
    |
    V

Now we execute
SELECT value + 1 FROM cte WHERE value < 4
Since cte is r1 (only has 2), we got:
  r2 = 3
  cte = r2 = 3

    |
    |
    V

Now we execute
SELECT value + 1 FROM cte WHERE value < 4
Since cte is r2 (only has 3), we got:
  r3 = 4
  cte = r3 = 4

    |
    |
    V

Now we execute
SELECT value + 1 FROM cte WHERE value < 4
Since cte is r3 (only has 4), we got:
  r4 = NULL (because r3 (4) is equal to 4, not less than 4)
Now we stop the recursion!

    |
    |
    V

Let's calculate the final result:
R = r0 union all
    r1 union all
    r2 union all
    r3 union all
  = 1 union all
    2 union all
    3 union all
    4 union all
  = 1
    2
    3
    4
```

Comment: This clarifies that it's not keeping a running set, but rather obtaining a separate result set at each level of recursion.  So it's not R1 = 1,  then R2 = (1 union all R1+1) = (1,2), and then R3 = (1 union all R2) = (1,1+1,2+1)=(1,2,3), etc.   Rather, it's only looking at the result using the immediately previous result set only and filtering that rather than the whole union. It only unions them all at the very end.  In other words, in uses the output of only the recursive member as input, not the output of the anchor unioned with the recursive member.

Answer (score 8):

I think it breaks down like this:

1. The anchor statement is executed.  This gives you a set of results, called the base set, or T0.
2. The recursive statement is executed, using T0 as the table to execute the query against.  This happens automatically when you query a CTE.
3. If the recursive member returns some results, it creates a new set, T1.  The recursive member is then executed *again*, using T1 as input, creating T2 if there are any results.
4. Step 3 continues until no more results are generated, OR the maximum number of recursions has been met, as set by the MAX_RECURSION option.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) probably explains it best.  It has a step-by-step walkthrough of the execution path of a CTE.

Comment: That's 3 of us linked to that article now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You were probably wanting [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).  No, the anchor is not executed multiple times (it couldn't be, then `union all` would require that all of the results appear).  Details at previous link.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

```
1 Europe NULL Europe
2 Asia   NULL Asia
```

Step 2:

```
1 Europe  NULL Europe
2 Asia    NULL Asia
3 Germany 1    Europe/Germany
4 UK      1    Europe/UK
5 China   2    Asia/China
6 India   2    Asia/India
```

Step 3:

```
1 Europe   NULL Europe
2 Asia     NULL Asia
3 Germany  1    Europe/Germany
4 UK       1    Europe/UK
5 China    2    Asia/China
6 India    2    Asia/India
7 Scotland 4    Europe/UK/Scotland
```

Step 4:

```
1 Europe    NULL Europe
2 Asia      NULL Asia
3 Germany   1    Europe/Germany
4 UK        1    Europe/UK
5 China     2    Asia/China
6 India     2    Asia/India
7 Scotland  4    Europe/UK/Scotland
8 Edinburgh 7    Europe/UK/Scotland/Edinburgh
```

Step 5:

```
1 Europe    NULL Europe                             0
2 Asia      NULL Asia                               0
3 Germany   1    Europe/Germany                     1
4 UK        1    Europe/UK                          1
5 China     2    Asia/China                         1
6 India     2    Asia/India                         1
7 Scotland  4    Europe/UK/Scotland                 2
8 Edinburgh 7    Europe/UK/Scotland/Edinburgh       3
9 Leith     8    Europe/UK/Scotland/Edinburgh/Leith 4
```

The last column in step 5 is the Level. During each level the rows get added with respect to what is already available. Hope this helps.