# How to yield recursion in query? What is the use of "With" ? How it works internaly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, recursion, oop

Why this query is completed with error ?

```
;with tempData as
 (
        select 32 as col1, char(32) as col2
        union all
        select col1+1, char(col1+1) from tempData
 )
select * from tempData
```

Comment: -1 for not reading MSDN but still managing to blunder into an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion needs a terminating condition. For example

```
;with tempData as ( 
select 32 as col1, char(32) as col2 
union all 
select col1+1, char(col1+1) from tempData 
where col1 < 255
) 
select * from tempData
option (maxrecursion 223)
```

With regards to the question in the title about how it works internally see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187850/how-does-a-recursive-cte-run-line-by-line/3187907#3187907).

Comment: - thanks for your answer its quit informative but now i want to know what is option(maxrecursion 0) ?

Comment: @Jeevan - By default CTEs will stop recursion after 100 levels. `option(maxrecursion 0)` means that it will continue recursion indefinitely (for ever if you have an infinite loop - or at least until SSMS runs out of resources!).

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop: where should it end?

Comment: You are right its infinit loop but i want to know how its loop because i dont know how 'With' works.