# Save temp list in recursive Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to make a Stored procedure which is made recursive

The database has a list of parts, and a part can be "containedin" another part so this "containedin" has an ID

I then want to make a function that

It will take one parameter "ID"

Print ID

Find ID on equipment which containedin is equal to this ID

Save these IDs in a list

Call this function again with all the IDs in the list

How do I make that list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is SQL Server 2005+ then use an inline TVF that contains a recursive CTE. Example Below.

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.EquipElement(
EquipmentID int not null primary key,
ContainedIn int null references EquipElement(EquipmentID),
Description varchar(20))    

INSERT INTO  dbo.EquipElement
SELECT 1, NULL, 'Breakfast' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'Fry Up' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'Coffee' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'Eggs' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, 'Bacon' UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2, 'Sausages' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 3, 'Milk' UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 3, 'Sugar'

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetBOM
(  
  @EquipmentID int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
  WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT EquipmentID,ContainedIn,Description 
    FROM dbo.EquipElement
    WHERE EquipmentID = @EquipmentID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.EquipmentID,e.ContainedIn,e.Description 
    FROM dbo.EquipElement e
    JOIN cte c on e.ContainedIn = c.EquipmentID
  )
  SELECT EquipmentID,ContainedIn,Description
  FROM cte
)

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.GetBOM(1)

SELECT * FROM dbo.GetBOM(3)
```

Comment: Good answer, I like common table expressions. Vote Up.

Comment: Well from what I can see, your example wont give me sub compoenents of the sub components What about this http://csharp.pastebin.com/0wUUTFYL

Comment: @Mech0z - Yes it will. See my edit for an example. It will carry on doing `UNION ALL` s on the result of the last `UNION ALL` until no more results are returned. I realise that isn't phrased very well! Better explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187850/how-does-a-recursive-cte-run-line-by-line/3187907#3187907)

Comment: How do I rewrite it to a Procedure then? And is this correct then http://csharp.pastebin.com/zmiVTtnQ (apart from it being a function instead of Procedure

Comment: Just call the TVF from your procedure.