# Help with recursive CTE query joining to a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, recursive-query

My objective is to recurse through table tbl and while recursing through that table select a country abbreviation (if it exists) from another table tbl2 and append those results together which are included in the final output.

The example I'll use will come [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187850/how-does-a-recursive-cte-run-line-by-line)

tbl2 has a Foreign Key 'tbl_id' to tbl and looks like this

```
INSERT INTO @tbl2( Id, Abbreviation, tbl_id ) 
VALUES 
 (100, 'EU', 1) 
,(101, 'AS', 2) 
,(102, 'DE', 3) 
,(103, 'CN', 5)
```

*Note: not all the countries have abbreviations.

The trick is, I want all the countries in Asia to at least show the abbreviation of Asia which is 'AS' even if a country doesn't have an abbreviation (like India for example). If the country does have an abbreviation **the result needs to look like this: China:CN,AS**

I've got it partly working using a subquery, but India always returns NULL for the abbreviation.  It's acting like if there isn't a full recursive path back to the abbreviation, then it returns null.  Maybe the solution is to use a left outer join on the abbreviation table? I've tried for hours many different variations and the subquery is as close as I can get.

```
WITH  abcd 
    AS ( 
          -- anchor 
        SELECT  id, [Name], ParentID, 
                CAST(([Name]) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path" 
        FROM    @tbl 
        WHERE   ParentId IS NULL 
        UNION ALL 
          --recursive member 
        SELECT  t.id, t.[Name], t.ParentID, 
                CAST((a.path + '/' + t.Name + ':' +                 
                (
                    select t2.abbreviation + ','
                    from @tbl2
                    where t.id = t2.id
                )) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path"

        FROM    @tbl AS t 
                JOIN abcd AS a 
                  ON t.ParentId = a.id 
       )
SELECT * FROM abcd
```

btw, I'm using sql server 2005 if that matters

Comment: what output are you looking for, columns and sample format please

Comment: the output you have below is just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this example, which will give you the output (1 sample row)

```
id  Name    ParentID    Path    abbreviation    (No column name)
5   China   2   Asia/China  CN,AS   Asia/China:CN,AS
```

The TSQL being

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( 
     Id INT 
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(20) 
    ,ParentId INT 
    ) 

INSERT INTO @tbl( Id, Name, ParentId ) 
VALUES 
 (1, 'Europe', NULL) 
,(2, 'Asia',   NULL) 
,(3, 'Germany', 1) 
,(4, 'UK',      1) 
,(5, 'China',   2) 
,(6, 'India',   2) 
,(7, 'Scotland', 4) 
,(8, 'Edinburgh', 7) 
,(9, 'Leith', 8) 

; 
DECLARE @tbl2 table (id int, abbreviation varchar(10), tbl_id int)
INSERT INTO @tbl2( Id, Abbreviation, tbl_id ) 
VALUES 
 (100, 'EU', 1) 
,(101, 'AS', 2) 
,(102, 'DE', 3) 
,(103, 'CN', 5)

;WITH abbr AS (
    SELECT a.*, isnull(b.abbreviation,'') abbreviation
    FROM @tbl a
    left join @tbl2 b on a.Id = b.tbl_id
), abcd AS ( 
          -- anchor 
        SELECT  id, [Name], ParentID,
                CAST(([Name]) AS VARCHAR(1000)) [Path],
                cast(abbreviation as varchar(max)) abbreviation
        FROM    abbr
        WHERE   ParentId IS NULL 
        UNION ALL
          --recursive member 
        SELECT  t.id, t.[Name], t.ParentID, 
                CAST((a.path + '/' + t.Name) AS VARCHAR(1000)) [Path],
                isnull(nullif(t.abbreviation,'')+',', '') + a.abbreviation
        FROM    abbr AS t 
                JOIN abcd AS a 
                  ON t.ParentId = a.id 
       )
SELECT *, [Path] + ':' + abbreviation
FROM abcd
```

Comment: That's better, but I'm still getting a null abbreviation for India using your query.  Notice, India does NOT have an abbreviation in tbl2, but I want it to output 'AS' because India is in Asia.

Comment: Are you sure? I cut and pasted into tempdb, and I get 6 | India | 2 | Asia/India | AS | Asia/India:AS

Comment: You're right!  I forgot to put an isnull() in there.  It's working now.  Thanks for the help!