# Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, split

I have a SQL Table like this:

| SomeID | OtherID | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef-..... | cdef123-... | 18,20,22 |
| abcdef-..... | 4554a24-... | 17,19 |
| 987654-..... | 12324a2-... | 13,19,20 |

Is there a query where I can perform a query like `SELECT OtherID, SplitData WHERE SomeID = 'abcdef-.......'` that returns individual rows, like this:

| OtherID | SplitData |
| --- | --- |
| cdef123-... | 18 |
| cdef123-... | 20 |
| cdef123-... | 22 |
| 4554a24-... | 17 |
| 4554a24-... | 19 |

Basically split my data at the comma into individual rows?

I am aware that storing a `comma-separated` string into a relational database sounds dumb, but the normal use case in the consumer application makes that really helpful.

I don't want to do the split in the application as I need paging, so I wanted to explore options before refactoring the whole app.

It's `SQL Server 2008` (non-R2).

Comment: See also: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 319, accepted):

You can use the wonderful recursive functions from SQL Server:

---

**Sample table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Testdata
(
    SomeID INT,
    OtherID INT,
    String VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,  9, '18,20,22';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 2,  8, '17,19';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 3,  7, '13,19,20';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 4,  6, '';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 9, 11, '1,2,3,4';
```

---

**The query**

```
WITH tmp(SomeID, OtherID, DataItem, String) AS
(
    SELECT
        SomeID,
        OtherID,
        LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
    FROM Testdata
    UNION all

    SELECT
        SomeID,
        OtherID,
        LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        String > ''
)
SELECT
    SomeID,
    OtherID,
    DataItem
FROM tmp
ORDER BY SomeID;
-- OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
-- normally recursion is limited to 100. If you know you have very long
-- strings, uncomment the option
```

---

**Output**

```
 SomeID | OtherID | DataItem 
--------+---------+----------
 1      | 9       | 18       
 1      | 9       | 20       
 1      | 9       | 22       
 2      | 8       | 17       
 2      | 8       | 19       
 3      | 7       | 13       
 3      | 7       | 19       
 3      | 7       | 20       
 4      | 6       |          
 9      | 11      | 1        
 9      | 11      | 2        
 9      | 11      | 3        
 9      | 11      | 4
```

Comment: The code doesn't work if change the data type of the column `Data` from `varchar(max)` to `varchar(4000)`, e.g. `create table Testdata(SomeID int, OtherID int, Data varchar(4000))`?

Comment: @NickW this may be because the parts before and after UNION ALL return different types from the LEFT function. Personally I don't see why you wouldn't jump to MAX once you get to 4000...

Comment: For a BIG set of values, this can overrun the recursion limits for CTEs.

Comment: @dsz That's when you use `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)`

Comment: The LEFT functions may need a CAST to work....for example LEFT(CAST(Data AS VARCHAR(MAX))....

Comment: POSTGRESQL - if you need this query in postgresql:
--  WITH    ->  WITH RECURSIVE
--  +   ->  ||
--  CHARINDEX   ->  POSITION
--  STUFF($a, $b, $c, $d)   ->  OVERLAY($a PLACING $d FROM $b FOR $c)
working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! What is the point of WHERE String > '' in the second select?

Answer (score 242):

Finally, the wait is over with **SQL Server 2016**. They have introduced the Split string function, [**`STRING_SPLIT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx):

```
select OtherID, cs.Value --SplitData
from yourtable
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (Data, ',') cs
```

All the other methods to split string like XML, Tally table, while loop, etc.. have been blown away by this `STRING_SPLIT` function.

Here is an excellent article with performance comparison: *[Performance Surprises and Assumptions: STRING_SPLIT](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/t-sql-queries/string-split)*.

**For older versions,** using *tally table* here is one split string function(best possible approach)

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
>         (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
> RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
>  RETURN
> --===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
>      -- enough to cover NVARCHAR(4000)
>   WITH E1(N) AS (
>                  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
>                  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
>                  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
>                 ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
>        E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
>        E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
>  cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
>                      -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
>                  SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
>                 ),
> cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
>                  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
>                  SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
>                 ),
> cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
>                  SELECT s.N1,
>                         ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
>                    FROM cteStart s
>                 )
> --===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
>  SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
>         Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
>    FROM cteLen l
> ;
> ```

Referred from **[Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)**

Comment: I would use STRING_SPLIT if only the server were on SQL Server 2016!  BTW according to the page you've linked to, the field name it outputs is `value`, not `SplitData`.

Comment: The accepted answer works, but considering the year is now 2021 this is the answer that should now take precedence. Thank you for this - SPLIT_STRING was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If original data contain rows with NULL values in the column to be split (column 'Data' in this question) by STRING_SPLIT, those rows are omitted in the result (column 'SplitData' in this question) when CROSS APPLY is used. To retain those, use OUTER APPLY.

Comment: Needs compatibility level 130 as well as SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 103):

Check this

```
 SELECT A.OtherID,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT OtherID,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Data, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  Table1
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Comment: When using this approach you have to make sure that none of your values contains something that would be illegal XML

Comment: This is great. Can I ask you, how would I rewrite that if I wanted the new column to only show the first character from my split string?

Comment: I have to tell you that method is "lovingl" (feel the love?) called the "XML Splitter Method" and  is almost as slow as either a While Loop or Recursive CTE.  I strongly recommend that you avoid it at all times.  Use DelimitedSplit8K instead.  It blows the doors off of everything except the Split_String() function in 2016 or a well written CLR.

Comment: @JeffModen This however has the advantage of being runnable in environments where function creation (even temporary functions) is not allowed/possible.

Comment: @Eduo - Perfect.  It can be comparatively super slow in every environment. ;)

Answer (score 36):

Very late but try this out:

```
SELECT ColumnID, Column1, value  --Do not change 'value' name. Leave it as it is.
FROM tbl_Sample  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ','); --'Tags' is the name of column containing comma separated values
```

So we were having this:
tbl_Sample :

```
ColumnID|   Column1 |   Tags
--------|-----------|-------------
1       |   ABC     |   10,11,12    
2       |   PQR     |   20,21,22
```

After running this query:

```
ColumnID|   Column1 |   value
--------|-----------|-----------
1       |   ABC     |   10
1       |   ABC     |   11
1       |   ABC     |   12
2       |   PQR     |   20
2       |   PQR     |   21
2       |   PQR     |   22
```

Thanks!

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` is nifty but it requires SQL Server 2016. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: elegant solution.

Comment: yes, @SangramNandkhile truly said, this is the most elegant solution, no need to declare any variable, nicely commented code, this is what I wanted. Thanks to Dungeon

Comment: There are many good answers here but this one was brief.  It also enabled pulling only a specific item from the array using row_number as an ordering method and modulus to pull only the one record from the array listed in the field.  Saved having to rewrite a split function as well.

Comment: Wonderful stuff

Comment: What about instances where Tags is null?

Answer (score 23):

```
select t.OtherID,x.Kod
    from testData t
    cross apply (select Code from dbo.Split(t.Data,',') ) x
```

Comment: Does exactly what I was after, and easier to read than many of the other examples (provided there's already a function in the DB for delimited string split). As someone not previously familiar with `CROSS APPLY`, that's kinda useful!

Comment: I couldn't understand this part 
(select Code from dbo.Split(t.Data,',') ) ?
*dbo.Split* is an table where is this exist and also *Code* is the Column in Split table ? i couldn't find the list of those table or values in anywhere in this Page ?

Comment: My working code are:
`select t.OtherID, x.*
from testData t
cross apply (select item as Data from dbo.Split(t.Data,',') ) x`

Answer (score 15):

As of Feb 2016 - see the TALLY Table Example - very likely to outperform my TVF below, from Feb 2014.  Keeping original post below for posterity:

---

Too much repeated code for my liking in the above examples.  And I dislike the performance of CTEs and XML.  Also, an explicit `Id` so that consumers that are order specific can specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @Line nvarchar(MAX),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5) = ','
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Data nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Line IS NULL RETURN;

    DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn);
    DECLARE @start_at INT = 1;
    DECLARE @end_at INT;
    DECLARE @data_len INT;

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@Line,@start_at);
        SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@Line) ELSE @end_at-@start_at END;
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) VALUES( SUBSTRING(@Line,@start_at,@data_len) );
        IF @end_at = 0 BREAK;
        SET @start_at = @end_at + @split_on_len;
    END;

    RETURN;
END;
```

Answer (score 12):

Nice to see that it have been solved in the 2016 version, but for all of those that is not on that, here are two generalized and simplified versions of the methods above.

The XML-method is shorter, but of course requires the string to allow for the xml-trick (no 'bad' chars.)

**XML-Method:**

```
create function dbo.splitString(@input Varchar(max), @Splitter VarChar(99)) returns table as
Return
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS Data FROM
    ( SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@input, @Splitter, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

**Recursive method:**

```
create function dbo.splitString(@input Varchar(max), @Splitter Varchar(99)) returns table as
Return
  with tmp (DataItem, ix) as
   ( select @input  , CHARINDEX('',@Input)  --Recu. start, ignored val to get the types right
     union all
     select Substring(@input, ix+1,ix2-ix-1), ix2
     from (Select *, CHARINDEX(@Splitter,@Input+@Splitter,ix+1) ix2 from tmp) x where ix2<>0
   ) select DataItem from tmp where ix<>0
```

**Function in action**

```
Create table TEST_X (A int, CSV Varchar(100));
Insert into test_x select 1, 'A,B';
Insert into test_x select 2, 'C,D';

Select A,data from TEST_X x cross apply dbo.splitString(x.CSV,',') Y;

Drop table TEST_X
```

**XML-METHOD 2: Unicode Friendly**  (Addition courtesy of Max Hodges)

`create function dbo.splitString(@input nVarchar(max), @Splitter nVarchar(99)) returns table as
Return
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS Data FROM
    ( SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@input, @Splitter, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);`

Comment: This may seem obvious, but how do you use these two functions? Especially, can you show how to use it in the OP's use case?

Comment: Here is a quick example: Create table TEST_X (A int, CSV Varchar(100));
Insert into test_x select 1, 'A,B';
Insert into test_x select 2, 'C,D';
Select A,data from TEST_X x cross apply  dbo.splitString(x.CSV,',') Y;
Drop table TEST_X

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Please refer below TSQL. STRING_SPLIT function is available only under compatibility level 130 and above.

TSQL:

```
DECLARE @stringValue NVARCHAR(400) = 'red,blue,green,yellow,black';
DECLARE @separator CHAR = ',';

SELECT [value]  As Colour
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@stringValue, @separator);
```

RESULT:

### **Colour**

red
blue
green
yellow
black

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @id_list VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234,23,56,576,1231,567,122,87876,57553,1216';
DECLARE @table TABLE ( id VARCHAR(50) );
DECLARE @x INT = 0;
DECLARE @firstcomma INT = 0;
DECLARE @nextcomma INT = 0;

SET @x = LEN(@id_list) - LEN(REPLACE(@id_list, ',', '')) + 1; -- number of ids in id_list

WHILE @x > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @nextcomma = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @id_list, @firstcomma + 1) = 0
                              THEN LEN(@id_list) + 1
                              ELSE CHARINDEX(',', @id_list, @firstcomma + 1)
                         END;
        INSERT  INTO @table
        VALUES  ( SUBSTRING(@id_list, @firstcomma + 1, (@nextcomma - @firstcomma) - 1) );
        SET @firstcomma = CHARINDEX(',', @id_list, @firstcomma + 1);
        SET @x = @x - 1;
    END;

SELECT  *
FROM    @table;
```

Comment: This is one of the few methods that works with the limited SQL support in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 6):

I know it has a lot of answers, but I want to write my version of split function like others and like string_split SQL Server 2016 native function.

```
create function [dbo].[Split]
(
    @Value nvarchar(max),
    @Delimiter nvarchar(50)
)
returns @tbl table
(
    Seq int primary key identity(1, 1),
    Value nvarchar(max)
)
as begin
    declare @Xml xml = cast('<d>' + replace(@Value, @Delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' as xml);

    insert into @tbl
            (Value)
    select  a.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from    @Xml.nodes('/d') a(split);
    
    return;
end;
```

- Seq column is primary key to support fast join with other real table or Split function returned table.
- Used XML function to support large data (looping version will slow down significantly when you have large data)

Here's a answer to question.

```
CREATE TABLE Testdata
(
    SomeID INT,
    OtherID INT,
    String VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,  9, '18,20,22';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 2,  8, '17,19';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 3,  7, '13,19,20';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 4,  6, '';
INSERT Testdata SELECT 9, 11, '1,2,3,4';


select  t.SomeID, t.OtherID, s.Value
from    Testdata t
        cross apply dbo.Split(t.String, ',') s;

--Output
SomeID  OtherID Value
1       9       18
1       9       20
1       9       22
2       8       17
2       8       19
3       7       13
3       7       19
3       7       20
4       6       
9       11      1
9       11      2
9       11      3
9       11      4
```

---

Joining Split with other split

```
declare @Names nvarchar(max) = 'a,b,c,d';
declare @Codes nvarchar(max) = '10,20,30,40';

select  n.Seq, n.Value Name, c.Value Code
from    dbo.Split(@Names, ',') n
        inner join dbo.Split(@Codes, ',') c on n.Seq = c.Seq;

--Output
Seq Name    Code
1   a       10
2   b       20
3   c       30
4   d       40
```

---

Split two times

```
declare @NationLocSex nvarchar(max) = 'Korea,Seoul,1;Vietnam,Kiengiang,0;China,Xian,0';

with rows as
(
    select  Value
    from    dbo.Split(@NationLocSex, ';')
)
select  rw.Value r, cl.Value c
from    rows rw
        cross apply dbo.Split(rw.Value, ',') cl;

--Output
r                       c
Korea,Seoul,1           Korea
Korea,Seoul,1           Seoul
Korea,Seoul,1           1
Vietnam,Kiengiang,0     Vietnam
Vietnam,Kiengiang,0     Kiengiang
Vietnam,Kiengiang,0     0
China,Xian,0            China
China,Xian,0            Xian
China,Xian,0            0
```

---

Split to columns

```
declare @Numbers nvarchar(50) = 'First,Second,Third';

with t as
(
    select  case when Seq = 1 then Value end f1,
            case when Seq = 2 then Value end f2,
            case when Seq = 3 then Value end f3
    from    dbo.Split(@Numbers, ',')
)
select  min(f1) f1, min(f2) f2, min(f3) f3
from    t;

--Output
f1      f2      f3
First   Second  Third
```

---

Generate rows by range

```
declare @Ranges nvarchar(50) = '1-2,4-6';

declare @Numbers table (Num int);
insert into @Numbers values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);

with t as
(
    select  r.Seq, r.Value,
            min(case when ft.Seq = 1 then ft.Value end) ValueFrom,
            min(case when ft.Seq = 2 then ft.Value end) ValueTo
    from    dbo.Split(@Ranges, ',') r
            cross apply dbo.Split(r.Value, '-') ft
    group by r.Seq, r.Value
)
select  t.Seq, t.Value, t.ValueFrom, t.ValueTo, n.Num
from    t
        inner join @Numbers n on n.Num between t.ValueFrom and t.ValueTo;

--Output
Seq Value   ValueFrom   ValueTo Num
1   1-2     1           2       1
1   1-2     1           2       2
2   4-6     4           6       4
2   4-6     4           6       5
2   4-6     4           6       6
```

---

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH tmp(SomeID, OtherID, DataItem, Data) as (
    SELECT SomeID, OtherID, LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1),
        STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
FROM Testdata
WHERE Data > ''
)
SELECT SomeID, OtherID, Data
FROM tmp
ORDER BY SomeID
```

with only tiny little modification to above query...

Comment: Can you briefly explain how this is an improvement over the version in the accepted answer?

Comment: No union all...less code.  Since it is using union all instead of union, shouldn't be a performance difference?

Comment: This didn't return all the rows it should have. I'm not sure what about the data requires the union all, but your solution returned the same number of rows as the original table.

Comment: (the problem here is that the recursive part is the one omitted...)

Comment: Not giving me expected output only giving first record in seperate row

Answer (score 3):

By creating this function ([DelimitedSplit]) which splits a string, you could do an OUTER APPLY to your SELECT.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a INNER JOIN E1 b ON b.N = a.N), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a INNER JOIN E2 b ON b.N = a.N), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

TEST

```
CREATE TABLE #Testdata
(
    SomeID INT,
    OtherID INT,
    String VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT #Testdata SELECT 1,  9, '18,20,22';
INSERT #Testdata SELECT 2,  8, '17,19';
INSERT #Testdata SELECT 3,  7, '13,19,20';
INSERT #Testdata SELECT 4,  6, '';
INSERT #Testdata SELECT 9, 11, '1,2,3,4';

SELECT
 *
FROM #Testdata
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[DelimitedSplit](String,',');

DROP TABLE #Testdata;
```

RESULT

```
SomeID  OtherID String      ItemNumber  Item
1       9       18,20,22    1           18
1       9       18,20,22    2           20
1       9       18,20,22    3           22
2       8       17,19       1           17
2       8       17,19       2           19
3       7       13,19,20    1           13
3       7       13,19,20    2           19
3       7       13,19,20    3           20
4       6       1   
9       11      1,2,3,4     1           1
9       11      1,2,3,4     2           2
9       11      1,2,3,4     3           3
9       11      1,2,3,4     4           4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an Example of How to use STRING_SPLIT

```
DECLARE @MY_VALUES NVARCHAR(100)

SET @MY_VALUES = 'Apple,Orange,Banana,Coconut'

SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@MY_VALUES, ',');
```

Result :

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
Coconut
```

Answer (score 2):

> When using this approach you have to make sure that none of your values contains something that would be illegal XML –  user1151923

I always use the XML method. Make sure you use VALID XML. I have two functions to convert between valid XML and Text. (I tend to strip out the carriage returns as I don't usually need them.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_ConvertTextToXML (@Text varchar(MAX)) 
    RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,CHAR(10),'');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,CHAR(13),'');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'<','&lt;');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'&','&amp;');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'>','&gt;');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'''','&apos;');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'"','&quot;');
    RETURN @Text;
END;


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_ConvertTextFromXML (@Text VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'&lt;','<');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'&amp;','&');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'&gt;','>');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'&apos;','''');
        SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'&quot;','"');
    RETURN @Text;
END;
```

Comment: There's a small problem with the code you've got there.  It'll change '<' to '&amp;lt;' instead of '&lt;' like it should.  So you need to encode '&' first.

Comment: There's no need for such a function... Just use the implicit abilities. Try this out: `SELECT (SELECT '<&> blah' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'next line' FOR XML PATH(''))`

Answer (score 2):

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitToRows (@column varchar(100), @separator varchar(10))
RETURNS @rtnTable TABLE
  (
  ID int identity(1,1),
  ColumnA varchar(max)
  )
 AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position int = 0;
    DECLARE @endAt int = 0;
    DECLARE @tempString varchar(100);
    
    set @column = ltrim(rtrim(@column));

    WHILE @position<=len(@column)
    BEGIN       
        set @endAt = CHARINDEX(@separator,@column,@position);
            if(@endAt=0)
            begin
            Insert into @rtnTable(ColumnA) Select substring(@column,@position,len(@column)-@position);
            break;
            end;
        set @tempString = substring(ltrim(rtrim(@column)),@position,@endAt-@position);

        Insert into @rtnTable(ColumnA) select @tempString;
        set @position=@endAt+1;
    END;
    return;
END;
```

Use case

```
select * from dbo.SplitToRows('T14; p226.0001; eee; 3554;', ';');
```

Or just a select with multiple result set

```
DECLARE @column varchar(max)= '1234; 4748;abcde; 324432';
DECLARE @separator varchar(10) = ';';
DECLARE @position int = 0;
DECLARE @endAt int = 0;
DECLARE @tempString varchar(100);

set @column = ltrim(rtrim(@column));

WHILE @position<=len(@column)
BEGIN       
    set @endAt = CHARINDEX(@separator,@column,@position);
        if(@endAt=0)
        begin
        Select substring(@column,@position,len(@column)-@position);
        break;
        end;
    set @tempString = substring(ltrim(rtrim(@column)),@position,@endAt-@position);

    select @tempString;
    set @position=@endAt+1;
END;
```

Comment: Using a while loop inside a multistatement table valued function is just about the worst way possible to split strings. There are so many set based options on this question already.

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server 2016 (13.x) onwards, a working option can be using [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for this task as follows:

```
SELECT tab.SomeID, tab.OtherID, value AS val
FROM tab
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', tab.Data, ']'))
```

**Output**:

| SomeID | OtherID | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef-..... | cdef123-... | 18 |
| abcdef-..... | cdef123-... | 20 |
| abcdef-..... | cdef123-... | 22 |
| abcdef-..... | 4554a24-... | 17 |
| abcdef-..... | 4554a24-... | 19 |
| 987654-..... | 12324a2-... | 13 |
| 987654-..... | 12324a2-... | 19 |
| 987654-..... | 12324a2-... | 20 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/q5EnAxtZ).

Answer (score 0):

Below works on sql server 2008

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by items) as row# 
from 
( select 134 myColumn1, 34 myColumn2, 'd,c,k,e,f,g,h,a' comaSeperatedColumn) myTable
    cross apply 
SPLIT (rtrim(comaSeperatedColumn), ',') splitedTable -- gives 'items'  column
```

Will get all Cartesian product with the origin table columns plus "items" of split table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to extract data

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT;
    SET @Iterator = 1;

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT;
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData);

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
        SELECT 
            Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)));

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2,
                LEN(@RowData));

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1;
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData);
    END;
    
    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Data)
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData));

    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Using a while loop inside a multistatement table valued function is just about the worst way possible to split strings. There are so many set based options on this question already.