# How do I select only one generation of a hierarchical tree using an table parent child relation with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say there is a table called people with the following columns:

- person_id (integer)
- parent_person_id (integer)
- name (varchar)

Now, let's say the table has being populated and the name values are just letters (A, B, C, D ...). Considering the parents of each we end up with a hierarchical tree like the one bellow. The values are on the format:

person_id, parent_person_id, name

- 1, 1, A
- 2, 2, B

  - 3, 2, C

    - 4, 3, D
  - 5, 2, E

    - 6, 5, F

      - 7, 6, G
      - 8, 6, H

Consider on the structure above, A & B as first generation, C & E as second generation, D & F as third generation and G & H as fourth generation. For the first generation elements, the parent_person_id is equal to the person_id of the element.

I need to write a query that allows me to select the names from a certain generation(first, second, third, fourth, etc) of the tree. As a result I could get a table with the names of the user from a certain generation. For example:

1st Generation

```
person name  |  parent name
A            |  A
B            |  B
```

2nd Generation

```
person name  |  parent name
C            |  B
E            |  B
```

3rd Generation

```
person name  |  parent name
D            |  C
F            |  E
```

4th Generation

```
person name  |  parent name
G            |  F
H            |  F
```

I would like to pass a parameter to define each generation should be listed as child on the following query.

```
SELECT
    child.name as 'person name',
    parent.name as 'parent name'
FROM
    people as child
JOIN 
    people as parent
ON 
    child.parent_person_id = parent.person_id
WHERE
    -- I NEED HELP HERE :)
;
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Vinicius, i think this question/answer could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522478/sql-query-for-tree-table

Comment: Could you provide a table with the results you're looking for?

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni, I added a few result tables to the question. Please note that each generation will generate different results. I could have it all on a table, but I'm looking for tables per generation.

Comment: Is there a maximum to the possible number of generations?

Comment: Ideally there would not be a max, but if that make it easier, I would go for 4 generations.

Answer (score 1):

This is verbose and ugly and will be slow, and it's limited to 4 generations, but I don't know how else it can be done.

```
SELECT person_name, parent_name FROM

    (SELECT child1.name AS person_name, parent1.name AS parent_name, '1' AS generation
    FROM people as child1
    JOIN people as parent1
    ON child1.parent_person_id = parent1.person_id AND child1.parent_person_id = child1.person_id

    UNION

    SELECT child2.name AS person_name, parent2.name AS parent_name, '2' AS generation
    FROM people as child2
    JOIN people as parent2
    ON child2.parent_person_id = parent2.person_id AND child2.parent_person_id <> child2.person_id AND parent2.parent_person_id = parent2.person_id

    UNION

    SELECT child3.name AS person_name, parent3.name AS parent_name, '3' AS generation
    FROM people as child3
    JOIN people as parent3
    ON child3.parent_person_id = parent3.person_id AND parent3.parent_person_id <> parent3.person_id
    JOIN people as grandparent1
    ON parent3.parent_person_id = grandparent1.person_id AND grandparent1.parent_person_id = grandparent1.person_id

    UNION

    SELECT child4.name AS person_name, parent4.name AS parent_name, '4' AS generation
    FROM people as child4
    JOIN people as parent4
    ON child4.parent_person_id = parent4.person_id AND parent4.parent_person_id <> parent4.person_id
    JOIN people as grandparent2
    ON parent4.parent_person_id = grandparent2.person_id AND grandparent2.parent_person_id <> grandparent2.person_id
    JOIN people as greatgrandparent
    ON grandparent2.parent_person_id = greatgrandparent.person_id AND greatgrandparent.parent_person_id = greatgrandparent.person_id
    ) AS tree

WHERE generation = ?
```

Comment: This works ok. I added an alias to the subquery to avoid error 1248.  Other bug is generation 2 that is returning generation 1 too.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've revised generation 2 to exclude generation 1.