# Returning all children with a recursive select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Good day everyone! I've got a graph. First, I know how to build **simple** recursive selections. I read some info on **msdn**.

[image: This is my sample graph]
In this image you can see that (for example) the top node of the graph, which is numbered 0, influences node number 1 (etc (2->4), (3->4), (4->5), (5->6), (1->5))

TASK: for **every** node show nodes which it influences. For example,
number 1 influences 5 and 6.

The result SQL must return something like this:

```
 who_acts| on_whom_influence 
 0       | 1
 0       | 5
 0       | 6
 1       | 5
 1       | 6
 2       | 4
 2       | 5
 2       | 6
 3       | 4
 3       | 5
 3       | 6
 4       | 5
 4       | 6
 5       | 6
```

Starting data that I can get using [anchor member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of CTE are:

```
who_acts| on_whom_influence 
2       | 4
3       | 4
4       | 5
5       | 6
1       | 5
0       | 1
```

Can I make this selection using SQL syntax and a recursive select? How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand, what is your desired end result? Could you show the result you'd want from the sample data, that may make it clearer.

Comment: You should include your table definitions and current anchor query. @Joachim the sample result is the first code block. It's a listing of nodes (who_acts) and all their children of any depth (on_whom_influence).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ,@EsotericScreenName  the result is the first block  after "as the result SQL must return something like this" . This is the result.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No, that **is** the desired result. The base data is only present in the question via the image.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Ok, with the image included that makes sense :)

Comment: I got the answer.A GREAT Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a straightforward CTE.  You can pass along the root of the influence in a separate column:

```
; with  Influence as
        (
        select  who_acts
        ,       on_whom_influence
        ,       who_acts as root
        from    dbo.YourTable
        union all
        select  child.who_acts
        ,       child.on_whom_influence
        ,       parent.root
        from    Influence parent
        join    dbo.YourTable child
        on      parent.on_whom_influence = child.who_acts
        )
select  root
,       on_whom_influence
from    Influence
order by
        root
,       on_whom_influence
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77709/2/0)