# Model Recursive relationship without graph database

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

We use Postgres as our database. Now have a new requirement to model relationships like follow. Though it seems like a good fit for a graph database, there is no room for using graph db as postgres has already been used as db platform in this application.

What's the best way to model this in a relational design to avoid recursive self joins which will result in horrible query performance for a large recursive tree. -

Query requirement is such that display `John Doe` 's relationship tree along with every related member's relationship tree in there.

Note that following example is for illustration purposes but real use case involves very deep such recursive relationships.

```
{
"personId" : 1,
"name" : "John Doe",
"relationships": {
  "cousineOf" : 23 //23 is a personId in the same table. say 23 is "Merry",
  "fatherOf" : 3 //where 3 is a personId with name - "George",
  "brotherOf" : 67 //where 67 is a personId with name - "Tony"

 }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what sort of queries you're going to be performing and you state that you want to model a recursive relationship without resorting to recursive queries? A bit more detail would be helpful...

Comment: @Ben : just added query requirement. let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Normally, you don't store siblings (there are too many of them ...) Just store the id's of the parent(s) in the person record. Plus, of course {gender , DOB , name} etc. Siblings can be derived from this hierarchy. (siblings share the same parents, cousins the same grandparents, etc)

Comment: Are you aware of the ability to do recursive queries in SQL? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would design the schema:

```
create table people (
  person_id int primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table relationships (
  from_person_id int references people(person_id),
  type text, --link to foreign table in real life
  to_person_id int references people(person_id),

  primary key (from_person_id, type, to_person_id)
);
```

Sample data:

```
insert into people values
(1, 'John Doe'),
(23, 'Merry'),
(2, 'George'),
(67, 'Tony');

insert into relationships values
(1, 'cousinOf', 23),
(1, 'fatherOf', 6),
(1, 'brotherOf', 67);
```

Please let us know what you want to do with the data. Some [tree and path examples](http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/02/trees-paths-recursive-cte-postgresql.html) using PostgreSQL Recursive CTEs.

[How does a Recursive CTE run, line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187850/how-does-a-recursive-cte-run-line-by-line)