# Can I select full hierarchy of parents when id and parent id are in the same table?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table which has a column for Id and parentId.  ParentId contains the Id of another row in the table.  If the ParentId is null then it is the top of the hierarchy.

I have the Id of a row and I want to select all rows above it in the hierarchy.  Can I do this in a single select?

so in this example:

Id  | parentId | other columns
 1  | null
 2  |  1
 3  |  2

if I have id=3 I want to select rows 1,2,3.

Can I do it in linq to sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single select using a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), however LINQ to SQL doesn't support this so you will have to create a stored procedure with the query and call that from LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757370/recursive-same-table-query-in-sql-server-2008/1758797#1758797)**, uses recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know LINQ, but as other answerers have written, many relational databases support Common Table Expressions (CTE) - but not all (Oracle comes to mind). And if supported, CTE is a good approach to retrieving the "ancestry".

That noted, there are some other approaches to consider in particular a bridge table or nested set. [See my question for some explanation of these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database) and other ways of representing hierarchical data. Briefly, a bridge table most likely updated using CTE from a trigger will easily give you all ancestors or descendants - just not how close. A nested set model will give you this information and how close at the expense of more expensive inserts and updates comparatively.